# Query question: finding the latest specific consecutive results only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I apologize in advance, I am certainly not a db expert, so might be asking something obvious here. I have a large postgreql table with the following (example) data :

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (ID int, componentid varchar(30), scanresult varchar(30), eventdatetime timestamp)
;
    
INSERT INTO t
    (ID, componentid, scanresult, eventdatetime)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', '123', '2018-02-20 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'A', '345','2018-02-20 00:00:01'),
    (3, 'A', '?','2018-02-20 00:00:02'),
    (4, 'A', '54','2018-02-21 00:00:01'),
    (5, 'A', '?','2018-02-21 00:00:02'),
    (6, 'B', '?','2018-02-21 00:00:03'),
    (7, 'B', '457645','2018-02-22 00:00:01'),
    (8, 'B', '?','2018-02-22 00:00:02'),
    (9, 'B', '56465','2018-02-22 00:00:03'),
    (10, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:01'),
    (11, 'C', '234234','2018-02-21 00:00:03'),
    (12, 'C', '33','2018-02-22 00:00:01'),
    (13, 'C', '55','2018-02-22 00:00:02'),
    (14, 'C', '?','2018-02-22 00:00:03'),
    (15, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:01'),
    (16, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:01'),
    (17, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:02'),
    (18, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:03');
;
```

What I trying to achieve is a query that counts the nummer of occurences -per component- that have a scanresult of ?. However, I must ONLY count if the latest and consecutive scanresults are ?

To make clear what I mean, for my example I am expecting:

- for component A : 1, because the last scanresult ?
- for component B : 0, last scan is not ?
- for component C : 5, because the last 5 scanresults are ? (the first ? is followed by a normal scanresult, ergo the records are not consecutive)

Can any of you help me out here?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/643d6b/2

Comment: 1) Please don't use images, use editable text (so that someone can copy your data if they wish to try a solution) 2) Please update your question with the SQL you've managed to write so far on your own

Comment: Please ensure all the information you provide is consistent. The column names and the example data in the image are different from what you've provided in the dbfiddle - please update one or the other so that they are aligned

Comment: I updated with fiddle data

Answer (score 0):

1. Determine continuity by comparing to [`lag()` or `lead()` window
   functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)
2. Use a stepping sum to only target the latest sequence of
   bad scans
3. Count the rows in that latest sequence, per component_id.

```sql
select componentid, count(*)filter(where is_latest_bad_scan_chain) 
from (  select *,(0=sum(continuity_counter)over w2) as is_latest_bad_scan_chain
        from (select *, case when scanresult='?' and '?'=lag(scanresult,1,'?')over w1 
                        then 0 else 1 end as continuity_counter
              from t
              window w1 as (partition by componentid order by eventdatetime desc, id desc) ) a
        window w2 as (partition by componentid order by eventdatetime desc, id desc) ) a
group by componentid
order by componentid;
```

| componentid | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 6 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/px9-Yp4y)

It's not possible to directly use a window function in a [`filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), or nest window functions directly, hence the subqueries. If you're not a fan of indentation, they [can be replaced](https://dbfiddle.uk/am-gw9uN) with [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Comment: The result is different than what you showed as the expected output because row `(10, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:01')` has the same timestamp as row `(15, 'C', '?','2018-02-23 00:00:01')` which puts its scan result in the middle of the most recent chain of `'?'`. If you prefer to disregard the `eventdatetime` and instead consider the `id` to dictate order and continuity, you can swap them. I figured that must've been an error in constructing the example, especially since originally your `id` column was of [`uuid` type that orders differently from `int`.](https://dbfiddle.uk/9RRP3t9k)

Comment: This is absolutely epic. My god, I could have never come up with that!!! Thanks a million!
Would this also work when the id is a UUID? or do we now depend on succeeding id's?

Comment: I addressed this in comment above: `uuid` orders differently from `int`. If you order by the `int` column, you'll get your expected result ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nMyCt6hN)), because row 10 will maintain its position in the partition with `C`'s. If you order by a `uuid`, you'll pretty much get random order compared to that. It made the most sense to me to order by `eventdatetime` instead, because an *id* is typically only meant to *uniquely identify* rows, with no guarantees as to maintaining order and continuity.

Comment: Even auto-generated, integer-based id's are usually based on [sequences, that don't guarantee order or continuity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html#id-1.9.3.81.7), at least not unless you establish some additional logic to guard and maintain it.

Comment: @drstruggle I think I misunderstood the question about `uuid`-dependence: yes, if you order by `eventdatetime` (that to me makes the most sense), you are free to use `uuid`-based `id`. And if you use `int`-based `id`, this doesn't care if they are successive, or if there are gaps between them. See [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/e5ajBerz) - `uuid`-based `id` changes nothing.

Comment: You are also correct. It seems as if my table in fiddle keeps getting changed somehow... I am sorry for the confusion! And thanks

Answer (score 0):

Number your rows per component backwards, so as to have the last entry numbered 1, the second last 2, etc. Then iterate through a component's rows as long as the barcode is a '?' (that is a recursive CTE in SQL). Then aggregate and count.

```
with recursive
  numbered as
  (
    select
      componentid, dt, barcode,
      row_number() over (partition by componentid order by dt desc, id desc) as rn
    from t
  ),
  results as
  (
    select componentid, dt, barcode, rn from numbered where rn = 1
    union all
    select n.componentid, n.dt, n.barcode, n.rn
    from results  r
    join numbered n on n.componentid = r.componentid
                   and n.rn = r.rn + 1
                   and n.barcode = '?'
    where r.barcode = '?'
  )
select componentid, count(*) filter (where barcode = '?')
from results
group by componentid
order by componentid;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ca1a4c/43

Comment: Brilliant also @Thorsten. Damnit, I envy you guys